# Select files based on content of a variable in Python

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to select from a list of CSV files, all the files that contain a string. The string is included in a variable. So far this is what I got, but it's not working:

```
import os, re
import glob

for x in range(1,3,1):
 id = ['sbj'+ str(x)]
 id = str(id)
 csvfile=[]
 for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
  if id in file:
   print(file)
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: `id` is the string representation of a list. Just remove the `[` and `]` when creating `id`.

Comment: @NicoBiagi
If it works, you should accept his answer, [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and [also](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @MuhdMairaj An answer has to first be posted before it can be accepted, that is to say, a comment cannot be "accepted", only appreciated.

Comment: @Booboo Yes, pardon me. I read the comment as a correct answer to his question.